# Prevent JavaScript/HTML Injection on "Request Entity" in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am not sure if **ServiceStack** has a mechanism to prevent "JavaScript/HTML Injection" on Entities (Request Entities) properties.

Also as per my understanding entity's properties of type **string** is prone to JavaScript/HTML injection

If there is no in built mechanism please suggest me a better option.

One of the option which i see is use to validate may be using **Fluent Validation** or any other validating library

Comment: Yes you should be using Fluent Validation or another validation mechanism to sanitise all the values that are passed as a request to your ServiceStack service. ServiceStack won't do this for you, after all sending HTML and/or JavaScript in a request to the service may be perfectly legitimate, (i.e. where your service is a content manager for a blog), and it's wrong to assume the request is an injection attack. ServiceStack isn't constricted to only being consumed by web applications, so it's up to the service to decide which values are appropriate. ServiceStack does from SQL injection though.

Comment: It makes sense & thanks @Scott . Let me check if there any other way of validating the same

Comment: Hi @Shil, have you tried the `[HtmlEncode]` attribute method? :)

Comment: Just started working on it. Will keep you updated. Thanks for sharing sample code

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use validation:

Yes you should be using Fluent Validation or another validation mechanism to sanitise all the values that are passed as a request to your ServiceStack service.

## Why ServiceStack shouldn't sanitise for you:

ServiceStack won't do this for you, after all sending HTML and/or JavaScript in a request to the service may be perfectly legitimate, (i.e. where your service is a content manager for a blog), and it's wrong to assume the request is an injection attack.

ServiceStack isn't constricted to only being consumed by web applications, so it's up to the service to decide which values are appropriate.

It should be noted that ServiceStack does prevent SQL injection by escaping all parameters.

## Encode HTML entities:

If you are concerned about HTML injection, then you should consider encoding HTML entities, then any unsafe values that are returned won't affect your result. You can do this easily using this request filter, and marking up your DTO with an attribute `[EncodeHtml]`.

```cs
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,dto) => {
    var dtoType = dto.GetType();
    var filteredProperties = dtoType.GetPublicProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && p.HasAttribute<EncodeHtmlAttribute>() && p.CanWrite);
    foreach(var property in filteredProperties)
        property.SetValue(dto, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(property.GetValue(dto, null)), null);
});
```

On your DTO add the `[EncodeHtml]` attribute to the properties you want to protect.

```cs
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test
{
    public string UnsafeMessage { get; set; }

    [EncodeHtml]
    public string SafeMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute declaration is simply:

```cs
public class EncodeHtmlAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Then when you send a request such as:

```
/test?unsafeMessage=<b>I am evil</b>&safeMessage=<b>I am good</b>
```

The result will be

```
UnsafeMessage: "<b>I am evil</b>"
SafeMessage: "&lt;b&gt;I am good&lt;/b&gt;"
```

I hope this helps.

---

As per your suggestion if you want to throw an exception on any DTOs that may contain HTML then you could use a more general check which prevents any HTML in any strings on the DTO by checking against a regular expression, but I'd do this sparingly.

```cs
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,dto) => {
    var dtoType = dto.GetType();
    if(!dtoType.HasAttribute<PreventHtmlAttribute>())
        return;
    var filteredProperties = dtoType.GetPublicProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
    foreach(var property in filteredProperties){
        var value = property.GetValue(dto, null) as string;
        if(value != null && Regex.Match(value, @"<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
            throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "400", "HTML is not permitted in the request");
    }
});
```

Then use this attribute:

```cs
public class PreventHtmlAttribute : Attribute {}
```

On the DTO:

```cs
[PreventHtml]
[Route("/test", "GET")]
public class Test
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The code is working as expected thank you so much @scott

Comment: I added an addtinal Attribute [IgnoreHtmlContent] to ignore the entire entity itself. Currently i am using [EncodeHtml] attribute as well. Not sure if this is the right way of handling the issue

Comment: @Shil I have updated to include more general code that will prevent any HTML from being included in a DTO.